# Generated YouTube Captions Displaying Automatically

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api

We have generated our own YouTube Captions and uploaded them and they were working perfectly until recently. The captions on any video that has these custom captions are automatically displaying in and iframe embeds on our website. Below is an example of the embed code we are using but I am wondering if anyone has any other ideas as to why this might be happening. We are planning on setting it back to automatic captions shortly if we can't get this resolved.

```
<iframe width="488" height="330" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Eax_JtRlMNE?list=PLrkRb9nzgclX5pn7G4Keslyb2xss4sKOI&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;hd=1&amp;vq=hd720&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

As far as I understand, cc_load_policy=1 option only works with YouTube generated captions.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean there is more than 1 set of captions for this video ? One that is shown when using iv_load_policy=1, but also another one, that should be shown with iv_load_policy=3.

Comment: cc_load_policy is ignored for html5 players. It seems to be different things: cc_load_policy is for captions and iv_load_policy is for annotations. It has happen before that player settings fail to work. If so, file a bug.

Comment: We have uploaded captions which I believe removes the automatic captions so, just one set. I think I will have to file a bug. Thanks.